# Why if $U$ is open in $\overline {\Bbb R}$ then $U\cap \Bbb R$ is open in $\Bbb R$ in this proof?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, proof-explanation, measurable-functions

Consider $f:\mathbb R\to\overline{\mathbb  R}$ defined as $f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x}, x\neq 0\\ \infty, x=0 \end{cases}$

$f$ is Borel-measurable:

Proof (of Daniel Wainfleet).

It suffices to prove that if $U$ is open in $\overline {\Bbb R}$ then $f^{-1}U$ is Borel in $\Bbb R.$

Let $g$ be the restriction of $f$ to the domain $D=\Bbb R$ \ $\{0\}.$ Now $D$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and $g:D\to \Bbb R$ is continuous.

$\color{blue}{\text{If $U$ is open in $\overline {\Bbb R}$ then $U\cap \Bbb R$ is open in $\Bbb R$}}$ and  $$f^{-1}U=A\cup B$$ where $$A=f^{-1}(U\cap \Bbb R)=g^{-1}(U\cap \Bbb R)$$ and $$B= f^{-1}(U \setminus \Bbb R).$$ Now $A$ is open in $D$ by continuity of $g,$ and $D$ is  open in $\Bbb R,$ so $A$ is open in $\Bbb R.$ So $A$ is Borel in $\Bbb R.$

And $B=\emptyset$ or $B=\{0\}$ so $B$ is Borel in $\Bbb R.$

So $f^{-1}U=A\cup B$ is Borel in $\Bbb R.$

Why the blue part of the proof?

What result is being used?

Comment: How is the topology on $\overset {-} {\mathbb R}$ defined?

Comment: As the union of intervals $(a,b)\cup[-\infty,a)\cup(a,\infty]\cup\{\emptyset\}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think it's because of this $\tau_{A}=\{A\cap G: G~\text{is open in }X\}$ and taking $A$ as $\mathbb R$ and $G$ as $U$, no?

Comment: @Isa I find it helpful to think of $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ as a circle, and $\Bbb{R}$ as the circle with a point removed. Since $\Bbb{R}$ is open in $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$, relatively open subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ will be open in $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$.

Comment: @TheoBendit ook :) though in the exercise is the opposite direction the one considered, open in $\overline{\mathbb R}$ then open in $\mathbb R$

Comment: @Isa Even easier: every open subset of $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ will intersect with $\Bbb{R}$ in a relatively open subset of $\Bbb{R}$, by definition of "relatively open".

Comment: Ping me tomorrow. I just saw this and it's 2 a.m. & I'm beat.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I commented on your answer yesterday asking something else and you _ignored me_. And then I had another doubt, and thought it was better to ask a new one

Comment: I may have forgotten to reply. Formulating a good response takes time. Sometimes I might pot it aside and return later. Are the responses to this Q satisfactory now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\color{blue}{\text{If $U$ is open in $\overline {\Bbb R}$ then $U\cap \Bbb R$ is open in $\Bbb R$}}$ it is because of the **topology**, this:

$$\tau_{A}=\{A\cap G: G~\text{is open in }X\}$$

when$$A\subset X$$

---

In the particular case of the exercise

As $\mathbb R\subset\mathbb{\overline {R}},$ the topology of $\mathbb R$ is defined as

$\tau_{\mathbb R}=\{\mathbb R\cap U: U~\text{is open in }\overline{\mathbb R}\}$

Answer (score 2):

$U$ is either

1. a complement of a compact set in the $\mathbb{R}$ topology, or
2. open in $\mathbb{R}$ topology.

Case 2 is trivial. For case 1, note that $U = U' \cup \{\infty\}$ so, $U\cap \mathbb{R} = U'$ and $U'$ is the $\mathbb{R}$-complement of a compact, so closed, set. So $U'$ is open and we are done.

Comment: $\mathbb R$- complement of a compact is closed?

Comment: Sorry, $U' = A^\complement$, $A$ is compact, so $A$ is closed, and $U'$ is the complement of a closed set. I wasn't clear on what the "so closed" was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}$ is a topological subspace of its two-point compactification $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. That's is what's being used.